# How to Update a flutter app on already published native java app in play console

Tags: android, flutter, replace, google-play, updates

I have an application on the Google Play Store, programmed natively with java.
The application is live on google play with users.
I now need to re-program it using the flutter platform.
How can I replace the old native application with the new flutter application without losing all users to the old one, or having users be forced to delete the old app and install a new one?
I have a great need for all users of the old application and I do not want to lose any of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can re-write your native app in flutter with the following things are taken care.

1. Need to use the same package name *(native version which is in Play Store)* for the Flutter.
2. Need to use the same `.keystore` or `.jks` for publishing re-written Flutter app in Play Store.
3. Version name and Version code should be incremented.

So when you publish the re-written Flutter app to the store, users who are using the native app will receive an update *(make sure you take care of #3)* of Flutter version of app.

Comment: I have tried this and app got updated. But old data got deleted, i need to get old datas like shared preferences from native application.

Comment: You can try to get the older data by using the same key that is used to store the data in older application. @kirubhasankar

Comment: I have found solution by using this plugin native_shared_preferences: ^2.0.7. You can get old native shared preference data. @ Swaminathan